# iOS 6 SLComposeViewController - creating a facebook post with text and URL - no image

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

Quite simply unable to make a post with just the text and NSURL object. I can do it with just the post, or with the post, NSURL and image, but ideally I'd just like to provide the link with the post.

It simply states "Cannot post to Facebook" as "The post cannot be sent because the connection to Facebook failed."

Is there anything I can do? I'm not using the Facebook SDK at the moment, but perhaps I might have to?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for now I'm able to leave the image part nil (still include the method, just leave the argument nil) and it will show the text and link only.

Answer (score 0):

We just started running in to this issue with code that was working correctly yesterday. Googling shows a lot of people having this issue sharing from other Apple apps today via native integration. I actually think this is an issue on Facebook's end.

I tried sharing a URL from Mobile Safari and it too fails with the same error. Can you confirm that Mobile Safari also fails to share?

Comment: Here's a thread about the issue on Mountain Lion. It also is not working from Safari. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4440559?start=0&tstart=0